# Changing the system clock in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have been trying to find a functionality to change the system clock in my iOS app. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Do I have access to changing the system clock?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt you have access to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

As a user, I'm happy about that.
As a developer, I wonder why you need this?

Comment: Imagine that you would want to build an app that easily makes you switch between several timezones because you are doing work with people around the world.
Am I understand you correctly that because of rights issues for apps, I can't change the system time, system timezone or anything regarding the time settings of the phone?

Comment: @beetree That's pretty much what the "World Clock" tab of the built-in clock application does.

Comment: Is it possible to do now as in ios6?Please let me know if its possible.